# call py.test from a PyQt script

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using QT and PyQt to make a UI for my python scripts.

Although the script that I call is running py.test, so from command line I use

`python -m py.test -k "basetests" mytests.py`

How can I do the same from another python script, which is the one used by PyQt, when I push a button?

In my PyQt file I did add the `clicked.connect(self.runtests)` method, so it will execute when I click the button,but now I do not know what to put in the `runtests` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not know what to put in the runtests function

Just use `os.system` to call the script:

```
def runtests (self):
    import os
    os.system('python -m py.test -k "basetests" mytests.py')
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about use this approach, since the tests are also written in python; so I thought there was a different way.

Comment: @newbiez your other option is to call some methods from `py.test/__main__.py` directly, but I doubt this would be better for that case.

Comment: BTW is there any difference between how os.system call python and how the terminal call it? I am using OSX

Comment: @newbiez `os.system` does a system call, so no difference. you get the same results (assuming you use the same directory and session variables)